# List of methods to assign to various classes C#

Tags: c#, list, action, unity-game-engine

I have a sandbox world in Unity with various GameObjects that will eventually have a set of interactions that the player can choose from once they click on this object (best example would be The Sims).

I basically want each object to contain a list of methods which have been assigned from another list of methods. So maybe there is a Tree with the "shake" method, I want to assigned the "shake" method to the Tree's interaction list but the shake method is defined in another class. I also might have a car which could also have the "shake" method.

I understand that I can have a list of Action.

```
List<Action> interactions = new List<Action>();
```

and that this list can be populated with methods but Is this the best solution for what I explained above, and can i somehow have a Enum with all possible interactions which would automatically call a particular method for the particular GameObject?

Comment: What you've proposed is a reasonable solution, based on what little you've shared.  What would you want to use the enum for?

Comment: @DanPuzey I maybe thinking about it slightly wrong, but I have have a list of available interactions like `Enum Interaction{ Shake, Climb }` that I can assigned to a `List<Interaction>` to make calling the interaction easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve and whether it is the best solution, but to me this sounds like a good use for the strategy pattern:

```
// This is the 'strategy' in your case
public interface IInteraction
{
    void Do();
}

public class GameObject
{
    // Here is your list of interactions - you can do whatever you want with it.
    public List<IInteraction> Interactions { get; set; }
}

// Here is an interaction
public class Shake : IInteraction
{
    public void Do()
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: If you added a `Name` property then the `enum` the poster suggests wouldn't be required, too.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I like the idea of using a interface for the `Interaction`. I'm basically trying to reuse predefined Interactions for various different objects. So I may have to have an `IIteractive` interface for the objects which contain the `List<IInteraction>`

Answer (score 1):

One approach to this would be to have each action defined as a MonoBehavior script of their own. Then all you need to do is attach each behavior to each game object as a component.

This would require you changing your pattern of having all the actions defined in another class, but should keep things pretty clean.

Then to do each action you could just check if that gameobject has that component and do its action.
`Shake s = gameObject.GetComponent<Shake>();

  if(s != null)

  {

    s.Shake(shakeParameters);

  }`

Comment: This is also a nice suggestion. So I could have a whole folder of possible interaction classes which I could simple attach and `GetComponent`. But is there anyway I can define the `IInteraction` interface on these classes, then on `void Start` check all my objects components against `IInteraction` and added them to a list. Making it easy to call them.

Comment: Absolutely. Each class has to inherit from MonoBehavior, but you can also have them implement whatever other interfaces you want. Make an `IInteraction` interface which defines a `DoInteraction` method or whatever, and that should just work. You can have multiple interfaces too, like `IInstantAction` with a `DoItNow` method, and a `IPassiveAction` interface with a `StartAction` and `StopAction` method. So it would just be `class MyClass : MonoBehaviour, IInteraction`